# How to Access Mono<T> While Handling Exception with onErrorMap()?

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive

In data class I defined the **'name'** must be unique across whole mongo collection:

```
@Document
data class Inn(@Indexed(unique = true) val name: String,
               val description: String) {
  @Id
  var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

  var intro: String = ""
}
```

So in service I have to capture the unexpected exception if someone pass the same name again.

```
@Service
class InnService(val repository: InnRepository) {
  fun create(inn: Mono<Inn>): Mono<Inn> =
      repository
          .create(inn)
          .onErrorMap(
              DuplicateKeyException::class.java,
              { err -> InnAlreadyExistedException("The inn already existed", err) }
          )
}
```

This is OK, but what if I want to add more info to the exceptional message like `"The inn named '$it.name' already existed"`, what should I do for transforming exception with enriched message.

Clearly, assign `Mono<Inn>` to a local variable at the beginning is not a good idea...

Similar situation in handler,  I'd like to give client more info which derived from the customized exception, but no proper way can be found.

```
@Component
class InnHandler(val innService: InnService) {
  fun create(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return innService
        .create(req.bodyToMono<Inn>())
        .flatMap {
          created(URI.create("/api/inns/${it.id}"))
              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(it.toMono())
        }
        .onErrorReturn(
            InnAlreadyExistedException::class.java,
            badRequest().body(mapOf("code" to "SF400", "message" to t.message).toMono()).block()
        )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorMap-java.util.function.Function-), you aren't going to have the value you want handed to you in `onErrorMap` as an argument, you just get the `Throwable`. However, in Kotlin you can reach outside the scope of the error handler and just refer to `inn` directly. You don't need to change much:

```
fun create(inn: Mono<Inn>): Mono<Inn> =
    repository
      .create(inn)
      .onErrorMap(
          DuplicateKeyException::class.java,
          { InnAlreadyExistedException("The inn ${inn.name} already existed", it) }
      )
}
```

Comment: Actually it's Mono because of using reactive-mongo, so can't call ${inn.name} directly.

Comment: OK, that's weird. Because I replicated this and was able to use ${inn.name} just fine.

Comment: I think my approach breaks reactive paradigm... And I guess been reactive already ensured the whole context between client and server wouldn't fall apart.

Comment: @Todd What is class.java means here